# How To Change Role With Capablity in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, subscriber

I have to create one role guest user not access anything In site... But admin verify user when user role. Like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){

         $id=isset($_GET['id'])
         $u = new WP_User($id);

        // Remove role
        $u->remove_role( 'Guests' );

        // Add role
        $u->add_role( 'subscriber' );
     }

 ?>
```

but user capability does not change I have. Note: Role with which capability adds work is same as Subscriber...

Answer (score 0):

To be on a very safe side... Simply install "User Role editor" from the WordPress plugin respository.

It allows you to create new role, and as well set it's capabilities.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/